# merge multiple rows into one with grouped records as new columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following dataset:

```
╔════════════════════╦════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║id                  ║key                 ║Value        ║  
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════╣             
║1                   ║name                ║A            ║
║1                   ║country             ║UK           ║
║2                   ║name                ║Z            ║
╚════════════════════╩════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Trying this on MySQL 5.6

```
create table sample (
  `id` int,
  `key` varchar(255),
  `value` varchar(255)
  );
  
  insert into sample (`id`,`key`,`value`) values
  (1,'name', 'A'),
  (1,'country', 'UK'),
  (2,'name', 'Z');
```

I need a query to transform this data such that all the data for every `id` appears as one row with `keys` appearing as additional columns with respective values. The number of `key-value` pairs is known and fixed. (in this case, it would be 2)

```
╔════════════════════╦════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║id                  ║name                ║country      ║  
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════╣             
║1                   ║A                   ║UK           ║
║2                   ║Z                   ║null         ║
╚════════════════════╩════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hey @hsnsd, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when key = 'name' then value end) as name,
       max(case when key = 'country' then value end) as country
from sample
group by id;
```

Comment: Neat and sweet!! Couldn't think of adding the `max` in my existing query.